# How to make part of my sentence left aligned and rest as right aligned

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Let say I have a sentence as `This is my whole sentence`.

Now I want a part of above sentence `This is` left aligned. And the remaining part of same sentence `my whole sentence` as right aligned.

*I basically wanted to have option to configure `Footer` of my document, as part to go left side and another part on the right side.*

Is there any way to achieve this with `Libre-office writer`?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using a tabulator - the tabulation character is entered from the keyboard using the Tab key, and the result of its application is controlled by the type of tabulator and its position on the ruler.

The video shows the formatting of the Header with a Tab. The same steps apply to both Footer and normal paragraph text.

1. Enter the text you want
2. Remove unnecessary (preset) Tabs from the Ruler - just drag them aside
3. By clicking on the Tab Type icon in the upper left corner, set the desired type of future tabulator
4. Place the cursor in the desired place of your text and press the Tab key

Tab types change cyclically with each click - Left (default), Right, Center, and By Decimal Separator (used to align numbers).

[image: Tab Types.png]

Use the [Edit Tabs](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/01/05030300.html) to fine-tune tab stops

[image: Insert Tab To Text.gif]